# How to create new DataFrame with dict

Tags: pyspark

I had one `dict`, like:

```
cMap = {"k1" : "v1", "k2" : "v1", "k3" : "v2", "k4" : "v2"}
```

and one DataFrame `A`, like:

```
+---+
|key|
+----
| k1|
| k2|
| k3|
| k4|
+---+
```

to create the DataFame above with code:

```
data = [('k1'),
    ('k2'),
    ('k3'),
    ('k4')]
A = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['key'])
```

I want to get the new DataFrame, like:

```
+---+----------+----------+
|key|   v1     |    v2    |
+---+----------+----------+
| k1|true      |false     |
| k2|true      |false     |
| k3|false     |true      |
| k4|false     |true      |
+---+----------+----------+
```

I wish to get some suggestions, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks everyone for some suggestions, I figured out the other way to resolve my problem with pivot, the code is:

```
cMap = {"k1" : "v1", "k2" : "v1", "k3" : "v2", "k4" : "v2"}
a_cMap = [(k,)+(v,) for k,v in cMap.items()] 
data = spark.createDataFrame(a_cMap, ['key','val'])

from pyspark.sql.functions import count
data = data.groupBy('key').pivot('val').agg(count('val'))
data.show()

+---+----+----+
|key|  v1|  v2|
+---+----+----+
| k2|   1|null|
| k4|null|   1|
| k1|   1|null|
| k3|null|   1|
+---+----+----+

data = data.na.fill(0)
data.show()

+---+---+---+
|key| v1| v2|
+---+---+---+
| k2|  1|  0|
| k4|  0|  1|
| k1|  1|  0|
| k3|  0|  1|
+---+---+---+

keys = spark.createDataFrame([('k1','2'),('k2','3'),('k3','4'),('k4','5'),('k5','6')], ["key",'temp'])

newDF = keys.join(data,'key')
newDF.show()
+---+----+---+---+
|key|temp| v1| v2|
+---+----+---+---+
| k2|   3|  1|  0|
| k4|   5|  0|  1|
| k1|   2|  1|  0|
| k3|   4|  0|  1|
+---+----+---+---+
```

But, I can't convert 1 to true, 0 to false.

Answer (score 29):

I just wanted to contribute a different and possibly easier way to solve this.

In my code I convert a dict to a pandas dataframe, which I find is much easier. Then I directly convert the pandas dataframe to spark.

```
data = {'visitor': ['foo', 'bar', 'jelmer'], 
        'A': [0, 1, 0],
        'B': [1, 0, 1],
        'C': [1, 0, 0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
ddf = spark.createDataFrame(df)

Output:
+---+---+---+-------+
|  A|  B|  C|visitor|
+---+---+---+-------+
|  0|  1|  1|    foo|
|  1|  0|  0|    bar|
|  0|  1|  0| jelmer|
+---+---+---+-------+
```

Comment: FYI for those spark.createDataFrame will not work as expected if the input data is a nested dict and you are looking for nested data to be structs. Even if you're not looking for structs, if your data is not nested to the same schema/depth, dataframe initialization will silently drop data with this approach.

Answer (score 13):

I just wanted to add an easy way to create DF, using pyspark

```
values = [("K1","true","false"),("K2","true","false")]
columns = ['Key', 'V1', 'V2']
df = spark.createDataFrame(values, columns)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sc = SparkContext()
spark = SQLContext(sc)
val_dict = {
            'key1':val1,
            'key2':val2,
            'key3':val3
            }

rdd = sc.parallelize([val_dict])

bu_zdf = spark.read.json(rdd)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, I suggest you to include at least some minimal explanation of it.

Comment: I also find this answer very useful, however it would be good if you could explain what "sc" or "spark" is.

Comment: i am very sorry for the incomplete definition,I have updated the answer I guess now this should solve the doubts ,

Answer (score 4):

The dictionary can be converted to dataframe and joined with other one. My piece of code,

```
data = sc.parallelize([(k,)+(v,) for k,v in cMap.items()]).toDF(['key','val'])
keys = sc.parallelize([('k1',),('k2',),('k3',),('k4',)]).toDF(["key"])
newDF = data.join(keys,'key').select("key",F.when(F.col("val") == "v1","True").otherwise("False").alias("v1"),F.when(F.col("val") == "v2","True").otherwise("False").alias("v2"))

 >>> newDF.show()
 +---+-----+-----+
 |key|   v1|   v2|
 +---+-----+-----+
 | k1| True|False|
 | k2| True|False|
 | k3|False| True|
 | k4|False| True|
 +---+-----+-----+
```

If there are more values, you can code that when clause as a UDF and use it.

Comment: Actually, there are more values, could you tell me how to construct the UDF?

Answer (score 2):

I parallelize `cMap.items()` and check if value equal to `v1` or `v2` or not. Then joining back to dataframe A on column `key`

```
# example dataframe A
df_A = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4']).map(lambda x: Row(**{'key': x})).toDF()

cmap_rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(cMap.items())
cmap_df = cmap_rdd.map(lambda x: Row(**dict([('key', x[0]), ('v1', x[1]=='v1'), ('v2', x[1]=='v2')]))).toDF()

df_A.join(cmap_df, on='key').orderBy('key').show()
```

**Dataframe**

```
+---+-----+-----+
|key|   v1|   v2|
+---+-----+-----+
| k1| true|false|
| k2| true|false|
| k3|false| true|
| k4|false| true|
+---+-----+-----+
```