# How to Convert Great Expectations DataFrame to Apache Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, great-expectations

The following code will convert an Apache Spark DataFrame to a Great_Expectations DataFrame. For if I wanted to convert the Spark DataFrame, `spkDF` to a Great_Expectations DataFrame I would do the following:

```
ge_df = SparkDFDataset(spkDF)
```

Can someone let me know how convert a Great_Expectation dataframe to a Spark DataFrame.

So what would I need to do to convert the new Great_Expectations dataframe `ge_df` back to Spark DataFrame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://github.com/great-expectations/great_expectations/blob/86eea6da29e834c7cbaaeb6321c4c7d3cc4adc3d/great_expectations/dataset/sparkdf_dataset.py#L535), the class `SparkDFDataset` holds the original pyspark dataframe:

> This class holds an attribute `spark_df` which is a spark.sql.DataFrame.

So you should be able to access it with :

```py
ge_df.spark_df
```

Comment: Thanks blackbishop. That actually answered my question, but what I was hoping was that I could use the same method of converting the Validation results from Great_Expectations into a dataframe.
For example if I were to write validation_result.spark_df I would get the following error message
```AttributeError: 'ExpectationSuiteValidationResult' object has no attribute 'spark_df'
Traceback (most recent call last):

AttributeError: 'ExpectationSuiteValidationResult' object has no attribute 'spark_df'```

Comment: @Patterson Oh I see. Not sure you can do this directly. My be you can use [`to_json_dict`](https://github.com/great-expectations/great_expectations/blob/d51afdd1af1ec1627cb5ee541847759255ce3bf1/great_expectations/core/expectation_validation_result.py#L167) on the `ExpectationSuiteValidationResult` to get a the result as python dict then create pyspark dataframe from it.

Comment: is that something you could provide some guidance on please

Comment: Or do you think I should open up another question?

Comment: @Patterson I can't try this right now but it should be easy to test it yourself.  First, get the result as dict `result_dict = validation_result.to_json_dict()`. Then create [spark dataframe using the dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43751509/how-to-create-new-dataframe-with-dict): `df = spark.createDataFrame(result_dict)`

Comment: thanks for your latest comments. I will try your suggestion